# Cleaning html text, issues with replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an editor that ads:

```
<p><br></p> or empty `p`, and I want to rplace or remove them.
```

I use:

```
  value = value.replace('<p><br></p>', '<br>').replace('<p></p>','').strip('<br>')
```

The problem is that sometimes remove everything, an in all cases for the first paragraph I always get: `p>`﻿(removes the first chracter in tag).

Comment: Have you included everything to reproduce this?

Comment: Because `str.strip(str)` removes *any* of the characters in the str, not the precise string given as argument: `"asdf".strip("fdsa")` will yield an empty string.

Comment: @9769953 I understand, so how can I remove from start and end, keeping the string order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in how you use the [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method, which removes any leading or trailing  sequence of the `'<br>'` characters. So `<b>hello</b>` would be stripped to `hello</`, for example.

If you want to remove any `<br>` in the beginning and in the end of the `value` string, you can do it like so:

```
if value.startswith('<br>'):
    value = value[4:]
if value.endswith('<br>'):
    value = value[:-4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on you solution, why not just do ?

```
value = value.replace("<p>", '').replace("</p>", '')
```

Shouldn't that be enough ?
All `<p>` and `</p>` would get replaced and the rest of string will remain untouched.

For `value = "<p><br></p>"` you will get `"<br>"`.
For `value = "<p></p>"` you will get `''`.
For `value = "<p></p>oueo<p>54<br>65</p>eoue<p></p>"` you will get `"'oueo54<br>65eoue'"`.